# How to limit acceptable input Japaneses Character on TEdit in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

How to limit acceptable input Japaneses Character on TEdit in Delphi?

I have one `TEdit` in Delphi XE8 that I require to input only Japanese Characters, so how can I do that?

Comment: Testing individual characters, it may be difficult to distinguish between Japanese and Chinese characters, [Testing for Japanese/Chinese Characters in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/786637/576719).

Comment: What I don't get is why you would want to do this.

Answer (score 3):

As LU RD mentioned it is difficult to distinguish Chinese/Japanese characters, but if you are Ok to test ranges of characters that may be Japanese as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_writing_system) you can use following function. You'll need to change you source file format to be Unicode to enter Unicode characters, you can do it by right-clicking in the editor and selecting File Format option.

```
function IsStringJapanese(const S: string): boolean;
var
  C: Char;
begin
  Result := True;
  for C in S do
  begin
    Result :=
      // kanji
      ((C >= '一') and (C <= '龿'))
      // hiragana
      or ((C >= 'ぁ') and (C <= 'ゟ'))
      // katakana
      or ((C >=  '゠') and (C <= 'ヿ'));
    if not Result then
    begin
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Second question is how to validate TEdit depends on whether you are using VCL or FMX. In VCL you can prevent typing in certain characters by processing KeyPress event as following

```
procedure TMainForm.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if not IsStringJapanese(Key) then
  begin
    Key := #0;
  end;
end;
```

but it does not prevent copy/pasting string to Edit, you'll need to validate text before you use it.

In FMX you can use OnValidating event

```
procedure TForm1.Edit2Validating(Sender: TObject; var Text: string);
begin
   if not IsStringJapanese(Text) then
   begin
     raise Exception.Create('Text not japanese');
   end;
end;
```